# "Command not found" lines on terminal startup

Tags: terminal, command-line, path, zsh

Whenever I open my terminal, these lines are displayed:

```
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:2: command not found: bin
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:4: command not found: bin
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:6: command not found: bin
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:8: command not found: bin
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:10: command not found: bin
/Users/USERNAME/.zprofile:12: command not found: bin
```

These are the first 12 lines of my `/.zprofile`:

```
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
alias gtkwave=open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-
bin source /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
```

Judging by the nature of the output, I'm assuming that something is wrong with my `/.zprofile` file, but I haven't been able to find the correct way to go in and edit it.

Here's the output that I receive when I type the `echo $PATH` command:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the first 12 lines of your `.zprofile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your `~/.zprofile`:

1. You have hard-wrapped (i.e., inserted newline characters inside) the `alias` lines, causing `bin` to start its own separate line. You need to keep everything on one line.
2. Shell aliases that include whitespace need to be enclosed in quotes.
3. You have multiple identical lines, which is generally not useful.
4. The invocation `source ~/.zprofile` is recursive and was probably intended as a shell command for you to manually enter after editing `~/.zprofile`.

I suspect that `~/.zprofile` should simply read:

```
alias gtkwave="open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-bin"
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a straightforward way to replace the contents of `~/.zprofile`:

```
echo 'alias gtkwave="open -a /Applications/gtkwave.app/Contents/MacOS/gtkwave-bin"' > ~/.zprofile
```

Note that if there are any other directives that you want to keep (you should examine all of the contents first, e.g., `cat ~/.zprofile`) then you need to edit instead of overwrite it. You can use any text editor you like. E.g.,

```
open -e ~/.zprofile
```

or

```
vi ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! I went and edited the contents of `~/.zprofile`, and the annoying lines went away.